# What's the correct method signature for getting the cause of an exception, typecast to the correct type?

Tags: java, generics, exception

I have a method getInstanceOfCause() that accepts an exception class and a Throwable, iterates through the cause of the Throwable and it's causes and returns the instance of the cause that matches the class passed as the first parameter. It looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionUtil {
    public static <T> T getInstanceOfCause(Class<? extends Throwable> expected, Throwable exc) {
        return (expected.isInstance(exc)) ? (T) exc : getInstanceOfCause(expected, exc.getCause());
    }
}
```

Let's assume that the expected type is indeed in the "cause-chain" and the call won't cause a NPE. I am able to use it so:

```
MyException myException = ExceptionUtil.<MyException>getInstanceOfCause(MyException.class, exception);
```

This is awkward as I have to specify the type twice. Is there any way to rewrite the method signature so that I can use it like below, while still ensuring at compile time that the type is a subclass of Throwable?

```
MyException myException = ExceptionUtil.getInstanceOfCause(MyException.class, exception);
```

or

```
MyException myException = ExceptionUtil.<MyException>getInstanceOfCause(exception);
```

Comment: `MyException myException = ExceptionUtil.getInstanceOfCause(MyException.class, exception);` passes compilation for me. Do you get a compilation error for that statement?

Comment: It does pass compilation. So does `String s = ExceptionUtil.getInstanceOfCause(MyException.class, exception);` which doesn't make sense. Want the compiler to catch such mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `T` *can* be inferred from your current method signature. One problem is that you can call it like this:

```
Foo foo = ExceptionUtil.getInstanceOfCause(MyException.class, exception);
```

which makes no sense.

I suppose you want to guarantee that the return value type and the type of class for the first parameter are the same?

You can make use of the generic parameter `T`:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> T getInstanceOfCause(Class<T> expected, Throwable exc) {
    return (expected.isInstance(exc)) ? (T) exc : getInstanceOfCause(expected, exc.getCause());
}
```

Note how I constrained `T` to `Throwable`, and used it in both `Class<T> expected` and the return value type. This guarantees that the return value type is the same as the type of the class passed in.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This works like a charm. I had thought of constraining T in the parameters as `...getInstanceOfCause(Class<T extends Throwable> expected...` but that didn't work. Didn't realize I can constrain while defining the generic return type instead!